# Refer a value from a key which is in the form tuple of multiple elements

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dic = {('UUU','UUC'):'F',('GUU','GUC','GUA','GUG'):'V'}
L =  ['UUU', 'GUG', 'GUU']
```

As you see each elements of list(L) are in dictionary as keys. Now i want to replace each elements of L by its corresponding values. Output would be:

```
output = ['F','V']
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Without duplicates? What have you tried simple looping over the dict and creating the list should work.

Comment: yes. Without duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to decompose the keys into individual elements, and create a new dict from those:

```
new_dic = {}
for k, v in dic.items():
    for sub_k in k:
        new_dic[sub_k] = v
```

Now it's a simple matter of looping through the list:

```
output = [new_dic[i] for i in L]
```

and you can de-duplicate with `set`:

```
output = list(set(output))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list compression:

```
In [1]:  dic = {('UUU','UUC'):'F',('GUU','GUC','GUA','GUG'):'V'}

In [2]:  L =  ['UUU', 'GUG', 'GUU']

In [3]:  list(set([v for k,v in dic.items() for x in L if x in k]))
Out [3]: ['V', 'F']
```